# MODBUS auto address assignment

Tags: serial-port, communication, serial-communication, modbus

Does anyone know of a scheme whereby MODBUS addresses can be automatically set?  In my situation I'll have a number of slaves power up and need some automatic way of assigning them addresses.

Comment: There is no such thing in the MODBUS protocol. You'll have to implement your own mechanism, but that's only possible if you can modify the MODBUS slaves. One possible solution: if each slave has a unique serial number, you could implement a bootp-like protocol. Or, you could decide that the last two digits of the serial number define the slave address.

Comment: As Alexandre suggested use jumper setting to choose the respective slave. Along with you need to mention the same slave id in your code while accessing those slaves.

Comment: That will not work, Modbus slaves are passive, they cannot know the ID that the other slaves have in order to self-assign a different one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I just came across this and thought I would give my answer just in case someone is attempting to do this now or in the future. If the goal is to assign a slave ID to a new slave (and you are developing the firmware for the slave devices), you can have the ID stored in a holding register that you can write a new ID to. This does require that:

1. You know the ID already. Maybe have all new slaves have a default ID, say ID = 1, so you know the ID beforehand.
2. You can only add one slave at a time and must change the ID before adding another slave to the network.
   For example:  Connect and power up the first slave device, which has a default ID of 1. Send a write command that will change the ID to 2 and send the master a response (using the slave ID of 1 in the response so it doesn’t timeout). Now the slave ID is 2. Next, add the next slave to the network, which it’s ID is 1. Now you have two slaves on the network with unique IDs. Just repeat as many of times that you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about SLAVE ID's?  If so, that's just not going to happen...  The SlaveID is vitally important for the Client to be able to address said slaves on the serial network.  (RS485 serial network, presumably...).

So, there is no way to even send out a Modbus message and address it to SlaveID 1, and then somehow get that device to be SlaveID 1, because ALL of the devices would attempt to respond, in that case.  Not to mention, there is *NO* method in Modbus to ASSIGN a Slave an ID...  On the flip side of this...

Are you talking about performing some type of query to ask the slave devices which Modbus *REGISTERS* they have? Again, there is no Modbus way to do this, but with some code, you COULD query 40001, and if you get an error 2 back, then you know that register is not available.  If you then loop through all of the registers, keeping track of which ones returned non-error, well--then you COULD do a form of "auto-configure", but... In all honesty?  I would NOT recommend this, and I don't see a lot of value to even DOING this, because you not only have to know the REGISTER numbers, **you have to know** **WHAT THE DATA IN THE REGISTER ACTUALLY MEANS!**

What exactly are you trying to do anyway?  Perhaps there is another way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

What you think you want: automatic Slave ID assignment in Modbus RTU.

What you actually want: constant, common Slave ID with Modbus TCP.

In a nutshell, all your Modbus Slave ID's get set to a fixed, common value and then you bridge them with a TCP stack that supports things like link-local addressing or DHCP. Then the TCP address assignment can be dynamically handled while preserving a constant SlaveID for each unit.

There are three broad options here depending on what hardware you already have:

1. There are commercial off-the-shelf devices (such as [this](https://ctlsys.com/support/modbus_tcp-rtu/)) that can emulate TCP over RTU. I've not delved too deep into what they support and how well they work.
2. You could also add a whole ton of TCP to RTU bridges which will have built-in management for the TCP/IP layer and then use real Ethernet cabling. For a lot of devices, this could get expensive fast, but with Ethernet you have all sorts of bonus features like basically unlimited distance and improved CRCs. If you're looking to do this on the cheap, grab a dual-port Linux SBC (such as [this](https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=248) or [this](https://wiki.radxa.com/RockpiE)) and throw mbusd (from [here](https://github.com/3cky/mbusd)) on it.
3. If you have access to or are developing the firmware yourself, you could adapt something like uIP (simpler) or lwIP (faster) to communicate over RS-485 (UART). This would certainly be the cheapest option. Note that you should also have the ability to detect collisions on RS-485 to implement an IP stack correctly -- this involves echoing the receiver at all times and checking that the data-in and data-out match.